# Linearly independent set question

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

If the vectors:
$$
 \left\{ (V_1,V_2 ,\ldots, V_n) \right\} 
$$
are L.I, prove that the same thing applies to:
$$
 \left\{ (V_1,V_2-V_1 ,\ldots, V_n-V_1) \right\} 
$$
What would be your way to prove it?

Comment: i would calculate an example at first to see how the proof works

Comment: That's exactly what I've done! haha

Answer (score 3):

Assume there is a linear combination of these vectors with not all-null coefficients equal to $0$

Find out that it implies the original set of vectors is not linearly independant. This should be quite fast, since you have a linear combination of the original vectors, but it is the hardest part.

Conclude

Answer (score 3):

Suppose
$$a_1 V_1 + a_2 (V_2 - V_1) + \dotsb + a_n (V_n - V_1) = 0$$
for some $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$. This amounts to
$$(a_1 - a_2 - \dotsb - a_n) V_1 + a_2 V_2 + \dotsb + a_n V_n = 0.$$
Now you should be able to conclude.

Comment: I was able to conclude it. i just wanted to check what approach would people use...

Answer (score 2):

The matrix made with the coordinates of the vectors in the second set with respect to the given basis is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1 & \dots & -1 & -1\\
0 & 1  & 0  & \dots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 1  & \dots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0  & 0  & 0 & \dots & 1 & 0\\
0  & 0  & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which clearly has rank $n$.